# WordPress site [without www] not same as site [with www]

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, dns, no-www

So I've seen this similar problem on stack a few times but none of the solutions worked for me. So I have a client site that works perfectly at:
imscs.com (with the WWW)

But the same site will not load the content correctly (without the WWW)

I cannot see the arrow icons on the opening slideshow and the custom webfont is missing. In my WordPress "General settings" the WP-address & Site-Address are  set to www.imscs.com. I've even tried adding this code to my .htaccess file above the line # BEGIN WordPress:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com [L,R=301]
```

What I do know is that my client's IT guy did something with the DNS settings in order to place the non-www domain to show the website, but I don't know what he did since it's hosted in their offices.

Comment: Your [DNS](http://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=imscs.com%0D%0Awww.imscs.com&type=&ns=resolver&useresolver=8.8.4.4&nameservers=) is configured how it should be, so it is something on the server (or on any firewalls etc prior to it)

Comment: Great. So that opens up a number of possible issues. I can't seem to figure it out since I feel like everything else is in order.